# UnoPlatoform Desktop App DataGrid Template Column with HyperlinkButton Command Binding issue using MVVM

Tags: datagrid, uwp-xaml, uno-platform, windows-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

We are developing Desktop application using UnoPlatform in which we are using **DataGrid** from **CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls** for displaying some data.

So, my requirement is to have **HyperlinkButton** for one of the DataGrid Column and am using DataTemplate as shown in below code to achieve the functionality.

Issue here is that how to Bind a Command which is there in ViewModel to HyperlinkButton click/Command event?

DataGrid ItemSource is Bind to **GridData** observable collection from ViewModel.

I am trying to Bind **ChildItemInvokedCommand** which is there in My StorageAccountViewModel  to HyperlinkButton **Command** however this is not working.

What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

**ViewModel :**

```
public partial class StorageAccountViewModel : ObservableObject
{
 public ObservableCollection<ChildFolder> GridData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ChildFolder>();

private IAsyncRelayCommand _childItemInvokedCommand;
public IAsyncRelayCommand ChildItemInvokedCommand => _childItemInvokedCommand ?? (_childItemInvokedCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand<ChildFolder>(OnChildItemInvoked));

   private async Task OnChildItemInvoked(ChildFolder item)
    {
            // get clicked item here for further functionality

    }
}
```

**ChildFolder.cs**

```
public class ChildFolder
    {
        [JsonProperty("folderName")]
        public string FolderName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("folderPath")]
        public string FolderPath { get; set; }        
    }
```

**Page.xamal:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MDTSStorageExplorer.Views.StorageAccountsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MDTSStorageExplorer.Views"
    xmlns:models="using:MDTSStorageExplorer.Models"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
<controls:DataGrid
             x:Uid="DataTable"
             x:Name="detailGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             GridLinesVisibility="None" 
              DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.GridData}" >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >
            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding FolderName}" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=ChildItemInvokedCommand}" >
                                               
                   </HyperlinkButton>
             </DataTemplate>
         </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
 </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The `DataContext` for your `HyperlinkButton` is of type `ChildFolder`.
`ChildFolder` does **not** have a property called `ChildItemInvokedCommand`. Therefore, the binding `Command="{Binding Path=ChildItemInvokedCommand}"` is invalid.

### Solution

Instead of using a collection of `ChildFolder`, you can create a collection of *ItemViewModels*.
You can define the item as follows.

```cs
public class ChildFolderItemViewModel
{
   public ChildFolder ChildFolder { get; set;}

   public StorageAccountViewModel ParentViewModel { get; set; }
}

// Then update your GridData to use the new type.
public ObservableCollection<ChildFolderItemViewModel> GridData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ChildFolderItemViewModel>();
```

Then, you can update your bindings as follows.

```xml
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding ChildFolder.FolderName}"
                 IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding ChildFolder}"
                 Command="{Binding ParentViewModel.ChildItemInvokedCommand}" />
```